# indexedDB - objectStore.openCursor() does not return all objects in the objectStore

Tags: indexeddb, cursors

I am trying to iterate on all the objects in my "product" objectStore using the openCursor() method.

```
function getAllProducts(){
    var products = [];
    var transaction = db.transaction(["product"], "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("product");

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
      var cursor = event.target.result;
      if(cursor) {
        products.push(cursor.value);
        cursor.continue();
      } 
    };
}
```

My "product" objectStore contains five (5) objects. So I am expecting that my products array will have a length of 5 also. However, upon checking via the log, it seems that the number of objects iterated is not constant. There are times that it only returns one (1) record and there are also time that it returns only two (2) records.

What is wrong with my code? Is there anything that I am missing?

I tried adding the onsuccess, onerror & onabort handles but there are still no additional logs in the console. Below's my updates code:

```
function getAllProducts(){
    var products = [];
    var transaction = db.transaction(["product"], "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("product");

    objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
      var cursor = event.target.result;
      if(cursor) {
        products.push(cursor.value.name);
        cursor.continue();
      } 
      console.log(products);
    };

    transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
    };

    transaction.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(event);
    };

    transaction.onabort = function(event) { 
        console.log("YO YO YO");
        console.error("transaction aborted");
     }; 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be because you are trying to read before cursor has finished looping/processing. I would suggest using a callback method, which would be called at the end of cursor processing with the final result set.
Something like (*throwing code to give you an idea*):

```
function get_object(object, callBack){
        var obj_list = [];
        var transaction = db.transaction([object],"readonly");
        var obj_store   = transaction.objectStore(object);

        obj_store.openCursor().onsuccess = function (event){
            cursor = event.target.result;
            if(cursor){
                console.log(cursor.value);
                obj_list.push(cursor.value);
                cursor.continue();
            }else{
                console.log("Done processing " + object + "...");
                if (callBack&& typeof(callBack) == 'function') {
                    callBack(obj_list);
                }
                return;
            }
        };
    }
```

And then use it as:

```
get_object("data_store", callBack);
function get_object_result_processor(resultSet){
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not using a db variable from a global scope.

Comment: This is a really common error among people who are getting started with InexedDB

Comment: It's fine saying this, but can we have an explanation why? There are numerous working examples of using a global db var out there on the internet.

Comment: The explanation is that you should only use a global db variable if you are very comfortable writing async code. If you have doubts, then avoid using one. The authors of examples on the Internet are not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

An IDBTransaction object has an oncomplete and onerror handle that gets called when the transaction finishes. Try adding these handlers in with some console messages to see if any issues are being raised. Something like:

```
transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  };


transaction.onerror = function(event) {
    console.error(event);
};
```

Also, how is the object store being populated? Could the getAllProducts() function be getting called before all 5 objects have been inserted?

Comment: Tried adding the said handlers and there were no messages logged. Does this mean that the transaction is also not completed since it did not also log anything?

Comment: so the transaction.oncomplete message wasn't logged? that means the transaction is hanging somewhere and not completing. what browser are you using?

Comment: Yup, that could be the reason for that one but how would I know why the transaction is not completed? BTW, I am using chrome.

Comment: Typically the transaction oncomplete won't fire if the onerror or onabort handlers are thrown. Try adding transaction.onabort = function(event) { console.error("transaction aborted"); };

Comment: are you able to provide all the javascript source as a plunk / jsfiddle?

Comment: I updated my question. Please see if i added the handles correctly. I'm pretty new with indexedDB and I don't have that much knowledge on its syntax.

Comment: have a look at this fiddle i created: https://jsfiddle.net/1o3ewx6L/8/ . If you wait for the alert about the store being created, then hit Add Products, wait for alert, then hit Get Products

Comment: Alert is done after the db was created and products added. But no alert after get products.

Comment: My mistake, after clicking Get Products, check the console. I've put the output in a console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Look for errors in your objectstore as well just in case, I added that below.  You can only know that there are no more products when your transaction fires the `oncomplete` handler; I moved your `console.log` to that event handler.  If you're still seeing incomplete results it must be something else.

```
function getAllProducts(){
    var products = [];
    var request;
    var transaction = db.transaction(["product"], "readonly");
    var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("product");

    transaction.oncomplete = function(event) {
        console.log(products);
        console.log(event);
    };

    transaction.onerror = function(event) {
        console.error(event);
    };

    transaction.onabort = function(event) { 
        console.log("YO YO YO");
        console.error("transaction aborted");
     }; 

    request = objectStore.openCursor();

    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
      var cursor = event.target.result;
      if(cursor) {
        products.push(cursor.value.name);
        cursor.continue();
      } 
    };

    request.onerror = function(event) {
      console.error(event.error);
    };

}
```